# starting 10 different thread in java at the sametime

Tags: java, multithreading

I have 10 different threads which I want to start at the same time. And by same time, I mean not by starting them sequentially (although this will be close).

What is the best way to achieve this in java?

Comment: If you need them to all start at the **exact** same time, use a `CountDownLatch`.

Comment: If you need "close enough" just start all ten in a row

Comment: Why all the downvotes?  This is a perfectly valid question, just in need of clarification.

Comment: Even then, it depends on what you mean by "exact". They'll _probably_ all wake up from the `CountDownLatch#await` within, say, a couple milliseconds of each other. But if you're on a 4-core machine, there's just no way you'll get 10 threads to all start at exactly the same time -- the computer can only run 4 threads at a time. Starting 10 threads at the same time is a means, not an end goal -- what's your end goal?

Comment: @MattBall can you please provide an example by whch we can start the 10 different threds at the same time through countdown latch

Comment: @sonumkumar Check out this example: http://pastebin.com/VULjrJDN . On my machine, with no JIT warmup or anything (just running that code straight-up), they all start within 2 ms. YMMV, but this is about the closest you'll get to "at the same time."

Comment: @MattBall you should make that an answer which some small sample code.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html

Answer (score 4):

To be accurate: You will not be able to start all 10 threads at the exact same time. There will be some difference in the order ms or ns. You can just try to minimize this difference. And even then: If you have less cores than threads the first couple of threads will have done some work before the others even run their first instruction.

Comment: Well, what is the "same time" depends on what difference you can or are willing to measure. For many people the same ms is "the same time" for others a ps may not even be close enough. ;) But I will modify it.

Comment: Under high load situations, it may be impossible to start the threads so they all begin to execute "at the same time".  These are good warnings.

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice example of using a `CountDownLatch` for that in the Javaspecialists newsletter [The Law of the Corrupt Politician](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue152.html).

```
public class TestCorruption {
  private static final int THREADS = 2;
  private static final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(THREADS);
  private static final BankAccount heinz = new BankAccount(1000);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++) {
      addThread();
    }
    Timer timer = new Timer(true);
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
      public void run() {
        System.out.println(heinz.getBalance());
      }

    }, 100, 1000);
  }

  private static void addThread() {
    new Thread() {
      {
        start();
      }

      public void run() {
        latch.countDown();
        try {
          latch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          return;
        }
        while (true) {
          heinz.deposit(100);
          heinz.withdraw(100);
        }
      }

    };
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the number of cores your computer have, those will be the number of started threads on the same time, it is my first comment here so i hope this is correct.

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Practica {

    private static final int NUMTHREADS = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CountDownLatch cdl = new CountDownLatch(NUMTHREADS);
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMTHREADS);
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMTHREADS; i++) {
            executor.submit(new Imp(cdl));
            cdl.countDown();
            System.out.println("one thread sumbmited "+cdl.getCount());
        }
        System.out.println("All threads submmited");
        executor.shutdown();
    }

}

class Imp implements Runnable {
    CountDownLatch cdl;

    public Imp(CountDownLatch arg) {
        this.cdl = arg;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            cdl.await();
            System.out.printf("STARTED %s at %d millis%n",
                    Thread.currentThread().getName(),
                    System.currentTimeMillis());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```